# How can I check where date is not in range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to show the cars where it is not in range. How can I make this?

I have 2 tables

```
cars:

id, (string)
name, (strng)
status (string)
cover (string)

Booking:
id, (int)
car_id, (int)
daterange (tsrange),
created_at (timestamp)
```

```
SELECT
      cars.id,
      cars.name,
      cars.status,
      cars.cover,
      b.id
FROM cars 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b
      ON booking.car_id = cars.id
WHERE ???
```

I dont know where I can check all booking dateranges that is not reserved (in range)

I have two parameters start_date and end_date:

€:[Link to sql editor](https://sqliteonline.com/)
Run this query

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- create a table
CREATE TABLE booking (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  car_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  booking_range tsrange NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO cars (id, name) VALUES (1, 'BMW');
INSERT INTO cars (id, name) VALUES (2, 'OPEL');
INSERT INTO cars (id, name) VALUES (3, 'MERCEDES');
INSERT INTO cars (id, name) VALUES (4, 'AUDI');

INSERT INTO booking (
  id, car_id, booking_range
) VALUES (1, 1, tsrange('04-14-2023', '04-20-2023'))
```

then select it

```
SELECT
  cars.id as car_id,
  cars.name,
  b.id
FROM cars 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b
  ON b.car_id = cars.id
WHERE NOT (tsrange('04-11-2023', '04-15-2023', '()') && b.booking_range);
```

Why are none of the cars returned?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: A first attempt: `... WHERE not tsrange(start_date, end_date) && daterange ...`.  Though this question needs more information 1) Type for start_date and end_date. 2) Some example starting data and expected output.

Comment: Is the goal to identify periods within the range of start_date to end_date when each car is available or is it to identify which cars are available for the entire date range?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you! but there is one issue, it shows me not all cars, it shows my only the cars that are also in booking id doesnt matter if the cars in range or not, so I want to show all cars if they are in booking id or not

Comment: Again some example input fdata and expected output would be help

Comment: None of the cars are being returned because the BMW's _booking_range_ overlaps the specified date range and _booking_range_ for the other cars is NULL because of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Adding `OR b.booking_range IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause would result in all but the BMW being returned.

Comment: You won't get all cars because the `tsrange('04-11-2023', '04-15-2023', '()')` intersects with `tsrange('04-14-2023', '04-20-2023')` and therefore meets the criteria ...I want to check if any car is in a booking range, if yes dont show it. You need to show what output you expect for the data provided.

Comment: Also not sure why you want exclusive bounds for both lower and upper bound. That would seem to lead to holes in your range comparisons.

Comment: From the examples, it looks like `daterange` would be a more appropriate type than `tsrange`. While half-open ranges are common for timestamps, which are generally treated as continuous values, fully-closed ranges are often better for discrete values like dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess at what you want:

```
--Shows BMW has booking, other cars don't
SELECT
  cars.id as car_id,
  cars.name,
  b.id
  FROM cars 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b
  ON b.car_id = cars.id
  AND  (tsrange('04-11-2023', '04-15-2023', '()') && b.booking_range)
;
 car_id |   name   |  id  
--------+----------+------
      1 | BMW      |    1
      2 | OPEL     | NULL
      3 | MERCEDES | NULL
      4 | AUDI     | NULL


--Shows no cars have a booking over range.
SELECT
  cars.id as car_id,
  cars.name,
  b.id
  FROM cars 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b
  ON b.car_id = cars.id
  AND  (tsrange('04-21-2023', '04-25-2023', '()') && b.booking_range)
;
 car_id |   name   |  id  
--------+----------+------
      1 | BMW      | NULL
      2 | OPEL     | NULL
      3 | MERCEDES | NULL
      4 | AUDI     | NULL
```

Comment: While the overlapping range test can be pushed up into the `JOIN`, leaving it in the `WHERE` clause more clearly expresses its use as selection criteria.

Comment: Except putting it the `WHERE` effectively negates the `LEFT JOIN` and will only return rows that exist in `booking`. Feel free to try it.

Comment: In a prior comment to the OP, I addressed the need to include `OR b.booking_range IS NULL` to avoid filtering out cars without bookings overlapping the range. There is a fundamental difference between describing the associations between tables in a query and selecting from the results of applying those associations. Keeping the selection criteria in the `WHERE` clause means the rest of the query can easily be turned into a view against which the selection criteria can be applied, not so when it's pushed into the `JOIN`. For a more complicated query, that might be an important consideration.

Comment: @JohnH the OR Operator was the thing that helped me!